# IBM Cloud Functions + Cloudant

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant, ibm-cloud-functions

I've an IBM Cloud Functions action called **dealership**. This action takes some information from a Cloudant database. If I run this action on IBM Cloud Functions web interface, I get the desired results, see picure below, then the action is OK:

[image: IBM CF WEB Results]

Then I make this action availble from web

[image: enable http request]

And then, if I call this action from web browser, postman, webapp, anything I got status 204 (no content). Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you called the base URL, not the URL with the JSON extension. Because web action can return different results, you need to add the [Functions content extension](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=openwhisk-actions_web#extra_features) to the base URL.

```
https://<apihost>/api/v1/web/<namespace_ID>/<packageName>/<actionName>.<ext>
```

Comment: Hi Henrik ! Nice to meet you. I put .json as you suggest. I can receive some little bit information but my body content shows body : [ ]

Comment: {
  "body": [],
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/json"
  },
  "statuCode": 200
}

Comment: The correct sender should return....{
  "body": [
    {
      "_id": "e93d6c17e47613e5b5e426bfc27f73e3",
      "_rev": "1-6d3a316e140863cdb147048888d26051",
      "car_make": "Audi",
      "car_model": "A6",
      "car_year": 2010,
      "dealership": 15,
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Berkly Shepley",
      "purchase": true,
      "purchase_date": "07/11/2020",
      "review": "Total grid-enabled service-desk"
    }
  ],
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/json"
  },
  "statuCode": 200
A

Comment: This is API endpoint https://us-east.functions.appdomain.cloud/api/v1/web/c1b04453-0e1d-493b-a3a7-02f5dd95feba/dealership-package/review.json?dealerId=15

Comment: The status code 200 says that the request was successful. Now, the question is whether you provide all the required parameters. Do you have some default parameters configured when testing it directly in Functions?

Comment: on my node.js endpoint works great adding .json but in python this problem remain.

Comment: In python only default paraments is the same on node, just authentication to Cloudant. The API I posted here need only one parameter named dealerId with value 15

Comment: and the Cloudant result is returned as result by the function?

Comment: Do You have any email or WhatsApp, I can send print. I'm using smartphone, I'm using IBM CF on mobile don't allow to copy code to paste here. My WhatsApp 5581996303366, fabiojvalentim@gmail.com

Comment: Your last question, yes.

Comment: I'm trying to solve this about a week :'(

Comment: Open a new question with the Python code

Comment: Alright, now its 4:34AM I'm going to take a nap, later I'll open with screenshots , thank you very much henrik